# Can I still travel on the Troika Card even if it goes into a negative balance?

Tags: public-transport, russia, moscow

On the London Oyster Card, you can go into a negative balance. TFL introduced a [one more journey option](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=2ahUKEwjfhcmW96jlAhWBtIsKHfX8DzgQFjACegQIDBAH&url=https%3A%2F%2Flondonist.com%2F2014%2F06%2Ftfl-introduces-one-more-journey-option-on-buses-this-weekend&usg=AOvVaw0sU4r9PM6Wl4-smfgeWtVU).

I was wondering if there are any similarities between this and the Moscow Troika Card. One journey on the Troika Card costs 38 rubles. Will I be able to enter underground if I only have 30 rubles, go into a balance of negative 8 and top it up at the end of the journey?

Comment: AFAIK the turnstile will not let you in with not enough money on the card, but I can't (yet) find this officially declared on the Moscow Metro web site.

Comment: @MichaelHampton "Проездной билет «Кошелек» предоставляет право проезда в трамвае, автобусе, троллейбусе, метрополитене, монорельсовой транспортной системе и МЦК в пределах уплаченной суммы." from the [rules](http://transport.mos.ru/#!/page/mostrans/oplata_proezda/ticket_rules). Means, the "Purse" ticket grants you the right to travel by tram, bus, etc. within the limits of the sum paid.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**No.**

This happened to me when I was in Moscow a few weeks ago and overestimated how much I had left on my Troika card. The red light on the turnstile lit up and the screen displayed a message informing me that I didn’t have enough balance. The turnstile did not activate to let me through until I went to the machine and topped up.

Answer (score 8):

No, unfortunately you don't have that option. But remember that you can go through the turnstile on right or on the left and use your bank card if it allows **contactless payments**. It will cost you 42 rubles, which is slightly more, but not as much as buying a single ticket for 55 rubles.

In general, you should be trying to use Troika as much as possible because if you transfer to the bus/tram/trolley and use the same Troika card as on the subway, you will be granted the **90 minute option**. It will charge you extra 21 rubles on top of 38 rubles you've already paid and upgrade your ticket to the 90-minute one which allows unlimited rides on the ground public transport provided you only have one subway ride. That's significantly cheaper than paying for the rides individually.